# No WiFi on a system76 laptop after upgrade to 15.04

Tags: networking, wireless, network-manager, laptop

I just upgraded System76 Gazelle laptop to 15.04 and wifi no longer works.

It sees many networks and tries to connect to mine, but fails repeatedly (`/var/log/syslog` seems to indicate authentication failure, but the password in the `/etc/NetworkManager/.../my-wifi` is, of course, correct).

I tried rebooting both the laptop and the wireless modem.

I also tried <kbd>Fn-F11</kbd> (which now turns on "airplane mode") with no  results.

I also tried wired internet which is also ignored.

How do I restore the WiFi?

PS. Also http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2275442

Comment: This isn't off-topic here, but there's a dedicated section for System76 on Ubuntu Forums, where employees regularly respond. http://ubuntuforums.org/forumdisplay.php?f=341

Comment: @muru: [thanks](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2275442)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Found an answer](https://lists.launchpad.net/kernel-packages/msg114390.html):

```
sudo mv /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-3160-12.ucode /lib/firmware/backup-iwlwifi-3160-12.ucode
sudo mv /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-3160-10.ucode /lib/firmware/backup-iwlwifi-3160-10.ucode
```

Reboot. Seems to be an issue with the firmware. After reboot I was able to connect again, so for me it is working.

Comment: Indeed, [this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1442411) does it!

Comment: This doesn't work for the System76 Lemur

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that when I upgraded, I too had no wi-fi on both my laptops. What I had manually connect to my internet connection again. After that it was all OK, but if I had not of done it the first tiem, I would not of got back on to the net.

Answer (score 0):

The problem that I am seeing is that with the 15.04 upgrade and all of these fixes, I can get the laptop to connect to an NG-mixed station but not to an N-only station.  All of my wireless AP's were set to N-only, and I have had to revert them to NG-mixed to get the connection.